# Merge [vis] and [vis.js]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Both [vis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vis) and [vis.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vis.js) refer to the same [JavaScript library](http://visjs.org/).

If the [vis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vis) is cleaned can a moderator create a synonym [visjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visjs) as is suggested in the comments on [Add periods (“.”) to the list of things that the tag picker ignores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157765/add-periods-to-the-list-of-things-that-the-tag-picker-ignores) to prevent the [vis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vis) to be recreated?

Comment: [vis] viz a viz [vis.js]

Comment: Let's keep [vis.js].

Comment: Screw ze `vis`.

Answer (score 11):

I took a slightly different approach given the low number of questions in that tag.

I cleaned up all [vis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vis) questions by:

- closing
- delete voting
- editing
- delete the tag when appropiate
- retag to [vis.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vis.js)

The tag [vis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vis) will be deleted at 03:00 UTC when the tag-cleanup script runs.

Comment: You'll probably find [vis] gets created again. Tags with a . don't show up in the suggestions until after you've typed the character after the dot, `vis.j`. I went through a similar exercise with the [video.js] tag, new users kept creating [videojs] until we finally made the dotless version a synonym of the established tag.

Comment: Hmm, that might be something to consider. Wonder if there is meta consensus about  that @misterben

Comment: OK, found the MSE feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157765/add-periods-to-the-list-of-things-that-the-tag-picker-ignores

Comment: @misterben you mean typing the tag on the tag input box or as "suggested tags"?

Comment: I mean typing in the tag input box.