# make [visjs] a synonym of [vis.js]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

Following the deletion of [vis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vis) [as discussed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312415/merge-vis-and-vis-js), it was mentioned:

> You'll probably find [vis] gets created again. Tags with a . don't show up in the suggestions until after you've typed the character after the dot, vis.j. I went through a similar exercise with the [video.js] tag, new users kept creating [videojs] until we finally made the dotless version a synonym of the established tag. – misterben Dec 15 '15 at 22:08

And now we have [visjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visjs) being [retagged manually](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15567098) to [vis.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vis.js) when it could be made synonym for a permanent solution.

Extending on this, if you are aware of any other dotted tags (maybe through a [data query](https://data.stackexchange.com)), then preemptively making dotless versions synonyms for all of them would be nice, [until this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157765/add-periods-to-the-list-of-things-that-the-tag-picker-ignores).

Comment: No idea what happened there, I blame myself. Here is a query again with [54 tags](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/643943) ...

Comment: Now visjs 7 followers 32 questions.

Comment: I've suggested the synonym, see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370862/3995261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[visjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visjs) is merged and syn'd to [vis.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vis.js)